# Security Management?

Tags: php, security

I am going to build a Site in PHP. But now a days there are many crackers who crack our sites. To stop them or to secure our site from them How can i manage the security of my site.The site is based on an Institute.

Please Give me some tips and references.

Thanks In Advance.

And sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 4):

This is an extremely broad topic to cover.

The following articles should provide you with a good start, and keep you occupied for some time:

- [Writing Secure PHP (4 parts)](http://www.addedbytes.com/writing-secure-php/writing-secure-php-1/)
- [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)
- [CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgeries)](http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries)
- [XSS (Cross Site Scripting)](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS))
- [Comprehensive PHP security guide](http://php.robm.me.uk/)
- [Storing user passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

Comment: Thank for the giving me references..thank a lot it helps alot

Comment: What ever happened to altruism? I'm just kidding.